# Batch file that sees whatever's in the 'example.data' file and sets it as a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here's an example:
example.data has the word 'ThisIsAName' inside it.
The batch file sees whatever's written in it (so ThisIsAName) and does the command:

```
set name=ThisIsAName
```

How can I do this?

Aslo, if 'example.data' does not exist it does this:

```
:register
set /p name=Choose your username:
echo %name% > "example.data"
goto end
```

Comment: Where is the example of the file? Surely there are other lines in the file which we need to consider?

Comment: @Gerhard Well it check if 'example.data' exists, if it does, it does this, if it doesn't, it goes to
`:register
set /p name=Choose your username:
echo %name% > "example.data"
goto end`
But I don't think that changes much.

Comment: @Gerhard 'example.data' would only have one word (so in this case ThisIsAName) so it would be the only line in the file.

Comment: Are you looking for this: `set /P name="" < "example.data"`, or `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("example.data") do set "name=%%I"`?

Answer (score 1):

a Complete solution, including your current code:

```
@echo off
if not exist "example.data" goto :register

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("example.data") do set "name=%%i"
echo the variable is saved as %name%
goto :EOF

:register
set /p "name=Choose your username: "
(echo %name%)>"example.data"
goto end
```

a better solution might be to not use the label, check if the file exists, if not create it and still `set` the variable:

```
@echo off
if not exist "example.data" set /p "name=Choose your username: "
(echo %name%)>"example.data"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("example.data") do set "name=%%i"
echo the variable is saved as %name%
```

and as highlighted by user @Stephan, reading from the file (note this method as it only works if the file has only one line:

```
if exist "example.data" <"example.data" set /p "name=" 
if defined name goto :welcome
set /p "name=Choose your username: "
(echo %name%)>"example.data"
:welcome
echo welcome, %name%
```